# How to search based on multiple checkbox

Tags: php, sql

I have a form with checkbox based on which I want to made a search in sql table.

```
<input name="pc[]" type="checkbox" value="1">I  &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp   
<input name="pc[]" type="checkbox" value="2">II  &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp   
<input name="pc[]" type="checkbox" value="3">III
```

If checkbox 1 is ticked then the query should be like this

```
$result=$mysql_query="SELECT * FROM students1 WHERE PartCode IN ('1') ";
```

If checkbox 1 and 2 are ticked then the query should be like this

```
$result=$mysql_query="SELECT * FROM students1 WHERE PartCode IN ('1', '2') ";
```

etc.

For that purpose I wrote the following code. But its not working.

```
$ad = implode ("','",$_POST['pc']); 
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM students1 WHERE PartCode IN ('$ad') ");
```

how to edit the code?

Comment: So what's the question here? Are you getting an error? The wrong results?

Comment: what you get in `$ad`. Just echo the result is it display correct check box values.

Comment: I am getting Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the quotes for `$ad` from the query. Also your implode is not enclosing the values within quotes. So try with the following code:

```
$ad  = "'" .implode("', '", $_POST['pc']) . "'";   // outputs '1', '2' etc
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM students1 WHERE PartCode IN ($ad) ");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input name="pc[]" type="checkbox" value="1">I  &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp   
<input name="pc[]" type="checkbox" value="2">II  &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp   
<input name="pc[]" type="checkbox" value="3">III

<script>

jQuery("input[type=checkbox]").click(function(){
        var selectedCheckBoxArray = new Array();
        var n = jQuery("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length;
        if (n > 0){
            jQuery("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function(){
                selectedCheckBoxArray.push($(this).val());
            });
            //send check box data value array to server using Ajax

            $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "server_file.php",
                    data: { myCheckboxes:selectedCheckBoxArray },
                    success: function(data){
                        $('#myResponse').html(data);
                    }
            });

        }

    });
</script>
```